# Why am I getting no spaces between text node values?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-1.0

I am using Xpath expression to get text nodes from a XML document like below:

```
<company>
    <emp>
        <dept>Acct</dept>
        <salary>1000</salary>
        <proj>
            <under>E01</under>
             <under>E02</under>
        </proj>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <gender>male</gender>
    </emp>
</company>
```

I have written the following XPATH expression to get the text values :

```
normalize-space(string(//emp))
```

It is extracting the *correct* values and the output is like below:

```
Acct1000E01E02John Doemale
```

**Notice** that there are no spaces between the text node values from different nodes.

I **actually want** the output value to be in this way:

```
`Acct 1000 E01 E02 John Doe`
```

I have used `javax.xml.xpath` to parse and build the tree as follows:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
 Document document = builder.parse(new File("/employees.xml"));

 XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 String expression = "normalize-space(string(//emp))";
 String output= (String)xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

I am using JAVA SE 10 here. So, the Xpath version is 1.0

Is there a better way to extract the text values?
I am pretty new to XPath so any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost rigth here. 
Picking the [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/not) operator is the right way to go.
It should be something like this:

`/html/body/company/emp/*[not(self::gender)]`

That is, all childnodes of emp except `gender` node.
Here go a full exemple in javascript:

```
let xpathExpression = '/html/body/company/emp/*[not(self::gender)]';
let contextNode = window.document;
let xpathResult = document.evaluate(xpathExpression, contextNode, 
                                        null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

console.log(xpathResult.iterateNext());
console.log(xpathResult.iterateNext());
console.log(xpathResult.iterateNext());
console.log(xpathResult.iterateNext());
```

Comment: Thanks. But that only fulfills my second requirement. Can you suggest me how to achieve my first requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, this one is complicated...

First of all, you haven't tagged your question with an XPath version. Usually people who aren't aware of XPath versions are using the ancient version 1.0, so I'll make that assumption: sorry if it's wrong.

In XPath 1.0, a function that is given a node-set and that expects a string uses the string value of the first node in the node-set, taken in document order.

In your query

```
normalize-space(string(//emp))
```

`//emp` selects a node-set, which happens to contain a single node, so string() takes the string value of that node. The string value of an element node is the concatenation of all its descendant text node. The normalize-space function removes leading and trailing whitespace, and normalizes internal space to a single whitespace character.

You have shown your XML in indented form as

```
<company>
    <emp>
        <dept>Acct</dept>
        <salary>1000</salary>
```

etc, so it's reasonable to expect that the whitespace between elements forms part of the string value of the `<emp>` element. But you haven't told us how the document was parsed and turned into a node tree. Parsers often provide multiple options on how to do this, in particular, on how to handle the whitespace between element nodes. Most retain the whitespace by default, unless perhaps there is a schema or DTD that tells the parser that the whitespace is insignificant. Microsoft's MSXML parser, notoriously, drops the whitespace by default, which causes considerable problems when you are using XML to represent narrative documents, but actually makes life easier for people using XML for this kind of non-document data.

Your parser, for one reason or another (we can't tell) seems to have deleted the whitespace between element nodes. No XPath query is going to bring it back again. You may have options when building the document to retain the whitespace; that depends on the tools you are using.

Your second question asks about dropping one of the elements in the input. That's beyond the scope of XPath. XPath can only select nodes from the input, it cannot modify them in any way. To modify the tree, you need XSLT or XQuery.

Your attempt to solve the problem with `//emp[not(descendant::gender)]` is hopelessly doomed because this will only select employees that have no descendant element named `gender`. You appear to be guessing the semantics rather than using a specification or tutorial.

Comment: I have updated the question now with Xpath version and how did I build the tree. And I removed the second question as I asked it because of my misunderstanding of XPath and Xquery concepts.